# Is there a way to clone Hackage packages using command line tools?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

By that I mean clone them similarly to Github repos. 3.5 years ago I remember doing that in order to study some Haskell libraries, but after a long hiatus the way to do this from the command line using a tool like `stack` or `cabal` completely escapes me. I know that the package pages do have a direct tarball download at the bottom, but I remember there being something else. Just installing them gets rid of the sources, so that is not what I am looking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may

```
cabal unpack package-name
```

to get the latest version of `package-name` that `cabal` knows about, or

```
cabal unpack package-name-4.20
```

to get version 4.20 of `package-name`.

Comment: Hmmm...I remember the packages being downloaded and unpacked into the current directory. This is not what happens using `cabal fetch` right now. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Ah, it is possible using `cabal unpack`. That answers that.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Wow, great! I've updated the answer to reflect that better information.